# Copying Windows 7 to a new SSD drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone

I've upgraded my hard drive to a SSD (Solid State Drive) - whats the easiest way to copy my previous version of Windows 7 to the new SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Acronis DiskDirector: no luck**. Tried Acronis DiskDirector, no luck - after I cloned the drive, it gave an "BootMGR missing". Couldn't fix it by booting from a Windows 7 DVD and using the repair functionality.
- **Acronis TrueImage: worked**. Copied the primary windows HD to an image on an external HD, restored it to the SSD, then booted from the SSD.

Comment: Disk director is for partition management, not meant for copying entire disks. You find the right product for that in True Image.

Answer (score 2):

[DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) should suffice, and it's a free download.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) if you use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) you can also resize your partition before cloning if necessary, assuming the source is lager than the destination